# New to XML and looking for some guidance

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi everyone I am new to XML and I am trying to get my information to display like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLA3p.png)

I ran my XML through a validator and it has no errors but I can't get my xsl doc to connect. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help or explanation would be most appreciated. When I try to validate my xsl doc I keep getting back the error that the XML doc is not connected.
<-- START of XML -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hw3.xsl"?>
<!-- Simple XML file with no CSS -->




<Accounts>
<Client ID="CS5355">
<Name>
  <First>Grant</First>
  <Last>Wu</Last>
</Name>
<Address>
  <Street>55 Hawking Street</Street>
  <City>Delton</City>
  <State>MN</State>
  <Zip>89011</Zip>
</Address>
<Phone>(532) 555-9939</Phone>
<E-mail>gwu@brockton.com</E-mail>
<Account_Total>60000</Account_Total>
</Client>

<Client ID="CS5108">
<Name>
  <First>Cynthia</First>
  <Last>Browne</Last>
</Name>
<Address>
  <Street>71 Circuit Ct.</Street>
  <City>Wheaton</City>
  <State>MN</State>
  <Zip>89321</Zip>
</Address>
<Phone>(532) 555-3813</Phone>
<E-mail>cynthia@brownes.com</E-mail>
<Account_Total>80000
</Account_Total>
</Client>

<Client ID="CS5331">
<Name>
  <First>Robert</First>
  <Last>Olson</Last>
</Name>
<Address>
  <Street>5133 Oak Street</Street>
  <City>Delton</City>
  <State>MN</State>
  <Zip>89011</Zip>
</Address>
<Phone>(532) 555-8981</Phone>
<E-mail>rolson@delisp.net</E-mail>
<Account_Total>25000</Account_Total>
</Client>

<Client ID="CS5771">
<Name>
  <First>Steve</First>
  <Last>Bones</Last>
</Name>
<Address>
  <Street>900 Lawton Street</Street>
  <City>Wheaton</City>
  <State>MN</State>
  <Zip>89211</Zip>
</Address>
<Phone>(533) 555-5434</Phone>
<E-mail>Sbone@mail.com</E-mail>
<Account_Total>105000</Account_Total>
</Client>

<Client ID="CS5981">
<Name>
  <First>Jim</First>
  <Last>Wheatley</Last>
</Name>
<Address>
  <Street>Hawkes Lane</Street>
  <City>Delton</City>
  <State>MN</State>
  <Zip>89211</Zip>
</Address>
<Phone>(542) 555-8828</Phone>
<E-mail>jim_wheatley@kyu.edu</E-mail>
<Account_Total>83000</Account_Total>
</Client>

<Client ID="CS5308">
<Name>
  <First>Cindy</First>
  <Last>Kaufmann</Last>
</Name>
<Address>
  <Street>31 Alice Avenue</Street>
  <City>Delton</City>
  <State>MN</State>
  <Zip>89011</Zip>
</Address>
<Phone>(532) 555-7212</Phone>
<E-mail>cka@ispnet.net</E-mail>
<Account_Total>125000</Account_Total>
</Client>

<Client ID="CS5250">
<Name>
  <First>Lee</First>
  <Last>Hayes</Last>
</Name>
<Address>
  <Street>451 Unwin Ct.</Street>
  <City>Jasper</City>
  <State>MN</State>
  <Zip>89381</Zip>
</Address>
<Phone>(534) 555-9082</Phone>
<E-mail>leehayes@clarion.net</E-mail>
<Account_Total>118000</Account_Total>
</Client>

<Client ID="CS5981">
<Name>
  <First>Jane</First>
  <Last>Wilson</Last>
</Name>
<Address>
  <Street>87 Hilltop Drive</Street>
  <City>Jasper</City>
  <State>MN</State>
  <Zip>89381</Zip>
</Address>
<Phone>(534) 555-7493</Phone>
<E-mail>jwilson@cls.net</E-mail>
<Account_Total>95000</Account_Total>
</Client>

</Accounts>
```

<--START OF XSL-->

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
        <h1>List of Clients</h1>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor=" #0000FF">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Account Total</th>
          </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Accounts/Client">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Phone"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Email"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Account Total"/></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: From your code block for your XSLT it looks like you have some white space before the XML declaration. That's not allowed. An XML declaration is optional, but if it appears it must appear right at the start of the file,

Comment: Please give the exact text of the error message you see (the "not connected" error), and the name of the software that produced it; presumably a web browser.

Comment: It's worth developing and testing your XSLT code in a free-standing development environment before you try using it in a browser, because the error messages in a browser can often be obscure. (However, if you dig into the right place in the browser's development console, there may be more diagnostics than you realised.)

Answer (score 0):

If the element name is e.g. `Account_Total` then obviously in your XPath expression in the XSLT you need e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="Account_Total"/>` and not `<xsl:value-of select="Account Total"/>`.